# Entity Framework accessing data within include and .thenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

I am new to Entity Framework.

I understand the basics but am a little confused here.

```
await Context.PremiseContacts
             .Include(c => c.Contact)
             .ThenInclude(c => c.ContactEmails)
```

So imagine I have this code.

Contact is within premise contacts and then contact emails is within contact.

How would I access the contact emails data ?

I have tried this

```
Email = c.Contact.ContactEmails.,
```

when passing on the model but that is much options as I get and there should be more properties within contact email.

Essentially how do you access the data defined by .include and then how would you access the data defined by multiple includes/ then includes.

EDIT

Premise Contact

```
namespace SolaceSecure.DAL.Models
{
    [Table("premiseContact")]
    public partial class PremiseContact
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("premiseId")]
        public Guid PremiseId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("contactId")]
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
        [Column("isSolaceUser")]
        public bool? IsSolaceUser { get; set; }

        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public virtual Premise Premise { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Contact

```
  public Contact()
        {
            ContactEmails = new HashSet<ContactEmail>();
            ContactPhoneNumbers = new HashSet<ContactPhoneNumber>();
            PremiseComplianceContacts = new HashSet<PremiseComplianceContact>();
            PremiseContacts = new HashSet<PremiseContact>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("contactId")]
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("contactName")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        [Column("contactDescription")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string ContactDescription { get; set; }
        [Column("customerId")]
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Column("userId")]
        public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
        [Column("dateCreated", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [Column("dateModified", TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        [Column("modifiedBy")]
        public Guid? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        [Column("isDeleted")]
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        [Column("createdBy")]
        public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual Person CreatedByNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual Person ModifiedByNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Person User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContactEmail> ContactEmails { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ContactPhoneNumber> ContactPhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PremiseComplianceContact> PremiseComplianceContacts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PremiseContact> PremiseContacts { get; set; }
```

Contact Email

```
{
    [Table("contactEmail")]
    public partial class ContactEmail
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("contactEmailId")]
        public Guid ContactEmailId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("contactId")]
        public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
        [Column("emailTypeId")]
        public Guid EmailTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us, but it looks like `c.Contact.ContactEmails` will give you a collection of email objects, so you can't just assign it to your `Email` variable like this. You need to decide what happens when you have multiple contact emails.

Comment: Show us the class `PremiseContact` - we can't see your screen and magically read your code - you need to **SHOW US** the relevent bits

Comment: Have Updated :)

Comment: So I want to be able to access all of the properties in contact emails as email is just a string.

Comment: Is `c` a single `PremiseContact` or a collection?

Comment: `.ThenInclude` btw is EF Core method, so `[entity-framework-6]` tag is inappropriate.

Comment: So you can do `foreach(var contactEmail in c.Contact.ContactEmails) { var email = contactEmail.Email; }`, but we really don't know what you are trying to do here.